# LPX-00601 Invalid token in Oracle 10g XMLTABLE with namespaces

Tags: oracle10g, xml-namespaces

Trying to select some values from an XML with namespaces from a CLOB field in a table, in Oracle 10.2g, ends in

**ORA-31011: XML parsing failed**

**ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing**

**LPX-00601: Invalid token in '/*/par:PartItemAlternateIdTypeCode'**

More, replacing the prefixes of the namespaces with wildcard, rose same error.

The similar select upon an XML without namespace, works.

The error that appears in the **path clause** of the **XMLTABLE**, denote that Oracle 10.2 isn't able to deal with namespaces.

This works in Oracle 11 and above.. perhaps is a bug in 10.2g

Here is the query

```
create table efactura (efxml clob);

insert into efactura values (
'<mes:QueryPartItemRevisionResponseMessage xmlns:mes="http://xml.namespaces.test.com/im/dsp/services/managepartitem/message" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<par:PartItem xmlns:par="http://xml.namespaces.test.com/im/dsp/cdm/data/partitem">
<par:PartItemAlternateIdentifier>
<par:AlternateIdentifierSourceId>XYZ</par:AlternateIdentifierSourceId>
<par:PartItemAlternateIdTypeCode>Type Code1</par:PartItemAlternateIdTypeCode>
<par:PartItemAlternateIdVal/>
</par:PartItemAlternateIdentifier>
<par:PartItemAlternateIdentifier>
<par:AlternateIdentifierSourceId>XYZ</par:AlternateIdentifierSourceId>
<par:PartItemAlternateIdTypeCode>Type Code2</par:PartItemAlternateIdTypeCode>
<par:PartItemAlternateIdVal/>
</par:PartItemAlternateIdentifier>
<par:PartItemAlternateIdentifier>
<par:AlternateIdentifierSourceId>ABC</par:AlternateIdentifierSourceId>
<par:PartItemAlternateIdTypeCode>Type Code3</par:PartItemAlternateIdTypeCode>
<par:PartItemAlternateIdVal>00123456</par:PartItemAlternateIdVal>
</par:PartItemAlternateIdentifier>
</par:PartItem>
</mes:QueryPartItemRevisionResponseMessage>'
);
commit;

SELECT x.*
FROM efactura  t,
     XMLTable(
       XMLNamespaces(
        'http://xml.namespaces.test.com/im/dsp/services/managepartitem/message' AS "mes",
        'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "env",
        'http://xml.namespaces.test.com/im/dsp/cdm/data/partitem' AS "par"
       ),
       '/mes:QueryPartItemRevisionResponseMessage/par:PartItem/par:PartItemAlternateIdentifier' 
       PASSING xmltype(t.efxml)
       COLUMNS
         attrType VARCHAR2(25) PATH 'par:PartItemAlternateIdTypeCode',
         attrVal  VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'par:AlternateIdentifierSourceId'
     ) x
;
```

[LPX 00601 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyhAj.jpg)

Comment: Your code [doesn't throw that error](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hjo-uFlj), but also doesn't have the `/*/par:...` pattern in the error message you included. So it's unclear what you are actually doing. Possibly you have some other XML value that doesn't itself define `par`?

Comment: I am using oracle 10.2g, possibly in other version doesn't throw that error. I also tried other examples from oracle forums, which didn't work either, even the author said it works.. Maybe is a particular setting in my version? Anyway, I'll attach the image with the error.

Comment: It also works in 11gR2, which is as far back as I can go. If you're sure you're seeing this with *exactly* the XML and code you posted, then I can only suggest wild-carding instead - i.e. leave out the `xmlnamespaces` clause and use `*:` instead of  `mes:` and `par:` in the XMLTable.

Comment: Executing this query bring nothing
SELECT x.*
FROM efactura  t,
     XMLTable(
       '/*:QueryPartItemRevisionResponseMessage/*:PartItem/*:PartItemAlternateIdentifier' 
       PASSING t.efxml
       COLUMNS
         attrType VARCHAR2(25) PATH 'PartItemAlternateIdTypeCode',
         attrVal  VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'AlternateIdentifierSourceId'
     ) x
;
If I prefixed with *: in the path, same error